# Scrapy prints data in a csv file in every other row

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, web-scraping, scrapy

I've written a script in python scrapy, to parse some items from yellowpage. When I execute my script, it does parse all items flawlessly. However, I encounter problems whenever it comes to write those scraped data accordingly in a csv file which is When i open the csv file with data filled in I see that the data has got printed in every other rows. How can I get rid of blank rows? I'm pasting below the script information for your consideration.

"items.py" includes:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
class RealypItem(Item):
    Name = Field()
    Address = Field()
    Phone = Field()
```

"yp.py" aka spider contains:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
     name = "YellowPage"
     allowed_domains = ["yellowpages.com"]
     start_urls = ["https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=Coffee%20Shops&geo_location_terms=Los%20Angeles%2C%20CA&page=2"]

     def parse(self, response):
        page = response.xpath('//div[@class="info"]')
        for titles in page:
            Title = titles.xpath('.//span[@itemprop="name"]/text()').extract()
            Adr = titles.xpath('.//span[@itemprop="streetAddress" and @class="street-address"]/text()').extract()
            Tel = titles.xpath('.//div[@itemprop="telephone" and @class="phones phone primary"]/text()').extract()
            yield{'Name':Title,'Address':Adr,'Phone':Tel}
```

The command I'm using to run the script:

```
scrapy crawl YellowPage -o items.csv -t csv
```

Here is the partial picture of how the data filled in csv file looks like:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the actualy file contents rather than a screenshot? Maybe your software is just misinterpreting the csv?

Comment: Here is the link to that csv file: "https://www.dropbox.com/s/xt49h3p3hx7sn7l/items.csv?dl=0"

Comment: If you are on Windows, you are probably seeing bug https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/2672

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems to be ok, it's just that whatever software you are using to display your csv gets confused by your Windows newline character.

Generally the newline character is `\n` while on Windows it's `\n\r`. Scrapy being os aware adds Windows newlines instead of generic ones. Your csv program expects generic newlines but instead gets Windows ones.

The easiest fix here is to just delete `\r` characters from the file manually.

Comment: I'm sorry to comment just now as I was not around. Your solution seems to be very easy and interesting as well. However, could you tell where I can track this bug down to fix it, I meant where can I find it? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug. CSV is not really a visual doc format, it literally is just comma seperated values with one value per line. So you should be looking in configuring your visual program to interpret windows newline as  normal newline.

Comment: It's a windows issue.  I am struggling with it atm